# SQL error message ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql

```
create table LAB 
(
    lab_id number constraint lab_pk primary key, 
    test_name varchar(64), 
    results varchar(64), 
    collect_dtm date, 
    results_dtm date,
    specimen_code varchar(64),
    specimen_code_source varchar(64)  
);
```

```
select * from lab;
```

```
insert into lab (lab_id, test_name, results, collect_dtm, results_dtm, specimen_code, specimen_code_source)
values ('4', 'biopsy', 'negative', '07-JAN-23', 14-JAN-23, breast, SNOMED);

insert into lab (lab_id, test_name, results, collect_dtm, results_dtm, specimen_code, specimen_code_source) 
values ('5', 'urea', 'positive', '04-JUL-23', 06-JUL-23, urethra, LOINC);

select * from lab;
```

SQL Error message

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You must learn some SQL basic staff and I recommend to do that before you continue to work with SQL or to ask questions on Stackoverflow.
Oracle provides a set of rules which should generally be followed.

See [Oracle SQL rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E93130_01/xml_guide/Content/introduction/SQL_Standards.htm)

So you should check whether your SQL commands satisfy those rules. If not, they will likely be incorrect and must be fixed.

Have a look on your insert command:

```
insert into lab 
  (lab_id,test_name,results,collect_dtm, results_dtm,specimen_code,specimen_code_source) 
values 
  ('4', 'biopsy', 'negative','07-JAN-23', 14-JAN-23, breast, SNOMED);
```

You used single quotes around the four first values, you did not use them for the remaining three values.

Now read the rules from the link above. The second rule says:

> Each string (text) variable in a SQL statement should be enclosed in single quotes

So you hurt this rule. You missed to enclose some strings in your command in single quotes.

You also hurt this rule:

> A list of integer variables in a SQL statement must be enclosed in parentheses. Single quotes must not be used

The first column of your insert command is numeric, so the number must not be closed. In an insert command, doing it anyway will likely have no negative impact, but it is generally incorrect and should be avoided. It could lead to trouble in other cases.

So, following those rules, your insert command will be this one:

```
insert into lab 
  (lab_id,test_name,results,collect_dtm,results_dtm,specimen_code,specimen_code_source) 
values 
  (4, 'biopsy', 'negative','07-JAN-23', '14-JAN-23', 'breast', 'SNOMED');
```

And this command will successfully be executed, see this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XzV1NkxO)

Side note: You didn't use a date function when inserting your date. That's ok as long as you use Oracle's default date format `"DD-MON-YY"`.
But as soon as you use another format, you will get an error message. For example changing `'07-JAN-23'` to `'JAN-07-23'` will cause the insert command to fail again. A bit safer to avoid such possible issues would be to use a function that enforces a date according to the input format. So you could for example use `TO_DATE` like this:

```
insert into lab 
  (lab_id,test_name,results,collect_dtm,results_dtm,specimen_code,specimen_code_source) 
values 
  (4, 'biopsy', 'negative',
  TO_DATE('07-JAN-23','DD-MON-YY'), 
  TO_DATE('14-JAN-23','DD-MON-YY'), 'breast', 'SNOMED');
```